# How does Instagram have 'clean' fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, antialiasing

[image]

left is Instagram, right is mine..

Same font, Same color.. but mine (right) has some kind of RGB leak?

Comment: Can you share your relevant html and css?

Comment: it's not about html/css, Stackoverflow, Google, facebook all mainstream pages except Instagram and 'NEW' twitter have the same RGB leak problem, here's Stackoverflow: https://i.imgur.com/EO4qZzg.png | no problem @ new twitter: https://i.imgur.com/EvECtea.png | Tested @ Chrome, checked @ Photoshop zoom

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer to the "why" it is like that, but you could experiment with the following CSS properties:

```css
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale !important;
font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
```

or "hackier" approaches like:

```css
transform: rotate(-0.0002deg);
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

do any of those make a difference?

I checked instagram's css, but couldn't find any of those, so the "real" reason has to be something else... What OS are you checking on?

Comment: no difference, Windows - Chrome. Only way to recreate what Instagram has is to use filter: grayscale on fonts but then I can't change to RGB colors.. just white/offwhite/black

Comment: how about `text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px currentColor;`, does that make any difference?

Comment: nah, nothing changes.. (except it's bolder)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Instagram fonts](https://textandfonts.com/instagram-fonts/) tool for generating clean and awesome fonts. Give it a try and let me know.